# Location undefined for certain cases?

Tags: rascal

Suppose we have a function that extracts the line numbers of the lines that contain at least one statement. We apply a visit over most cases of

```
data Statement
```

in `lang::java::m3::AST`:

```
set[int] getStatLineNrs (Declaration d) {
  set[int] s = {};
  top-down visit(d) {
    case m:\enum(_,_,_,_)       : {s += {m@\src.begin.line}; }
    case m:\enumConstant(_,_,_) : {s += {m@\src.begin.line}; }
    ...
    //the following case gives: NoSuchAnnotation("src")
    case m:\variables(_,_)      : {s += {m@\src.begin.line}; } 
    ...
  }
  return s
}
```

This goes well for almost all cases, for one case however we get an error message `NoSuchAnnotation("src")`.

*Why is `m@\src` undefined for the case `case m:\variables(_,_)`?*

Answer (score 0):

In general an annotation is always an optional field which may not be there.

In particular for this case the missing annotation for the java ast is probably a minor bug in the translation from the Eclipse java compiler AST to the Rascal AST representation.

Answer (score 0):

PS. The case `\package(_)` has no \src annotation either, but I've managed to work around it.